# Get ItemsPanel from Items Control

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

So I am building a WPF drag and drop designer.

Once the user is done designing I want them to be able to print what they have.

This was working until I decided that all the items on my canvas should actually be databound to the view model. To do this I wrapped my canvas in a Items Control. The problem I am running into now is the print function I built can't access the canvas to print it. I am open to suggestions.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="CanvasItemsControl" Grid.Column="1" Width="600" Height="800"  ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasElements}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <Canvas Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True" Width="600" Height="800" 
                  x:Name="CanvasControl"                
                  Background="White"  
                  DragEnter="CanvasFlowDocument_DragEnter" 
                  DragLeave="CanvasFlowDocument_DragLeave" 
                  DragOver="CanvasFlowDocument_DragOver" 
                  Drop="CanvasFlowDocument_Drop"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <controls:CanvasElement />
           </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

C#

```
 private void PrintCanvas()
 {

   PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

   if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
   {

     /*

      NEED TO ACCESS CANVAS CONTROL HERE TO PRINT

      I KNOW THE BELOW PRINT METHOD WORKS. 

      IT WORKED UNTIL I ADDED THE ITEMS CONTROL WRAPPER AROUND THE CANVAS                

     */


      //get the size of the printer page 
      PrintCapabilities capabilities = pd.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(pd.PrintTicket);

      double pageMargin = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);

      double additionalMargin = Math.Max(0, 20 - pageMargin);
      Size pageSize = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth - additionalMargin * 2, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight - additionalMargin * 2);

      //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual 
      double scale = Math.Min(pageSize.Width / CanvasControl.ActualWidth, pageSize.Height / CanvasControl.ActualHeight);
      Size printSize = new Size(CanvasControl.ActualWidth * scale, CanvasControl.ActualHeight * scale);

      Point upperLeft = new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth + additionalMargin, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight + additionalMargin);

      //Transform the Visual to scale 
      CanvasControl.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
      CanvasControl.Measure(printSize);
      CanvasControl.Arrange(new Rect(upperLeft, printSize));


      FlowDocument CanvasFlowDocument = new FlowDocument();
      BlockUIContainer buiCont = new BlockUIContainer();


      CanvasControl.Drop -= CanvasFlowDocument_Drop;
      CanvasControl.DragOver -= CanvasFlowDocument_DragOver;
      CanvasControl.DragLeave -= CanvasFlowDocument_DragLeave;
      CanvasControl.DragLeave -= CanvasFlowDocument_DragEnter;


      Grid parent = (Grid)CanvasControl.Parent;

      parent.Children.Remove(CanvasControl);

      buiCont.Child = CanvasControl;
      CanvasFlowDocument.Blocks.Add(buiCont);

      pd.PrintDocument((CanvasFlowDocument as IDocumentPaginatorSource).DocumentPaginator, "Template");

      CanvasFlowDocument.Blocks.Clear();
      buiCont.Child = null;

      ReloadUI(parent);
   }
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to generate a bitmap from the `ItemsControl` element first, then print the bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [PrintDialog.PrintVisual(Visual,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual(v=vs.110).aspx) to print out your control directly.  You may need to play with size though, but the code you have to do the resizing should work.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175530/printing-of-wpf-window-on-one-page) which is similar and links to [this article](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=66#.VLlm8Xl0ywU) as a possible solution.