# WPF create Retangles using Vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to create a WPF windows application where it has to show all the Racks or shelves of Warehouse like below

So far this is what I have tried 
My Xaml looks like

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="950" Width="1225" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="3">
           <Grid>
          <Canvas Height="900" Width="1200" Name="front_canvas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="1,24,10,790" >
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />

                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                  </Canvas>
    </Grid>
        </Window>
```

In a Method I have following

```
For i As Integer = 1 To front_canvas.Width - 1 Step 100
        Dim rect As New Rectangle()
        rect.StrokeThickness = 1
        rect.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black
        rect.Width = 50
        rect.Height = 50
        rect.Name = "box" + i.ToString()
        'If Not i / 2 = 0 Then
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, i)
        Canvas.SetFlowDirection(rect, Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight)

        'Canvas.SetTop(rect, Top)
        '_top += rect.Height

        If front_canvas.Children.Count > 0 Then
            Dim lastChildIndex = front_canvas.Children.Count - 1
            Dim lastChild = TryCast(front_canvas.Children(lastChildIndex), FrameworkElement)
            If lastChild IsNot Nothing Then
                _top = Canvas.GetTop(lastChild) + lastChild.Height + 1
            End If
        End If
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, _top)
        front_canvas.Children.Add(rect)
        ' End If

        _rectangles.Add(rect)
    Next
```

And the result I get here is like below

[image]

I would appreciate if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Canvas Name="cvsWarehouse"></Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code Behind:

```
Imports System.Text

Class MainWindow

Private Const dRACKSIZE As Double = 57
Private Const dRACKSPACING As Double = 2
Private Const dAISLESPACING As Double = 40

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    CreateAisles()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateAisles()

    cvsWarehouse.Width = 10 + (11 * dRACKSIZE) + (6 * dRACKSPACING) + (4 * dAISLESPACING)
    cvsWarehouse.Height = 10 + (19 * dRACKSIZE) + (18 * dRACKSPACING)

    Dim dStartX As Double = 10

    CreateAisle(dStartX, 10, 19, 2, 1)
    dStartX += dAISLESPACING
    CreateAisle(dStartX, 10, 19, 2, 2)
    dStartX += dAISLESPACING
    CreateAisle(dStartX, 10, 19, 2, 3)
    dStartX += dAISLESPACING
    CreateAisle(dStartX, 10, 19, 2, 4)
    dStartX += dAISLESPACING
    CreateAisle(dStartX, 10, 19, 3, 5)

End Sub

Private Sub CreateAisle(ByRef dStartX As Double, dStarty As Double, iRowCount As Integer, iColCount As Integer, iAisleNumber As Integer)

    Dim iColUpper = iColCount - 1
    Dim iRowUpper = iRowCount - 1

    For iCol As Integer = 0 To iColUpper
        Dim dYOffset As Double = dStarty
        For iRow As Integer = 0 To iRowUpper
            Dim bdr As Border = GetNewBorder()
            bdr.Child = GetNewTextBlock(iAisleNumber, iCol + 1, iRow + 1)
            Canvas.SetTop(bdr, dYOffset)
            Canvas.SetLeft(bdr, dStartX)
            cvsWarehouse.Children.Add(bdr)
            dYOffset += dRACKSIZE + dRACKSPACING
        Next
        dStartX += dRACKSIZE + dRACKSPACING
    Next

    dStartX -= dRACKSPACING

End Sub

Private Function GetNewBorder() As Border

    Dim bdr As New Border
    bdr.Width = dRACKSIZE
    bdr.Height = dRACKSIZE
    bdr.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red
    bdr.BorderThickness = New Thickness(1)
    bdr.CornerRadius = New CornerRadius(2)

    Return bdr

End Function

Private Function GetNewTextBlock(iAisle As Integer, iCol As Integer, iRow As Integer) As TextBlock

    Dim txtBlock As New TextBlock()
    txtBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    txtBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("A").Append(iAisle.ToString()).Append(":C").Append(iCol.ToString()).Append(":R").Append(iRow.ToString())
    txtBlock.Text = sb.ToString()

    Return txtBlock

End Function
```

End Class

if you want to use buttons instead of borders that have event handlers attached:

```
    Private Sub CreateAisle(ByRef dStartX As Double, dStarty As Double, iRowCount As Integer, iColCount As Integer, iAisleNumber As Integer)

    Dim iColUpper = iColCount - 1
    Dim iRowUpper = iRowCount - 1

    For iCol As Integer = 0 To iColUpper
        Dim dYOffset As Double = dStarty
        For iRow As Integer = 0 To iRowUpper
            Dim btn As Button = GetNewButton()
            btn.Content = GetNewTextBlock(iAisleNumber, iCol + 1, iRow + 1)
            Canvas.SetTop(btn, dYOffset)
            Canvas.SetLeft(btn, dStartX)
            cvsWarehouse.Children.Add(btn)
            dYOffset += dRACKSIZE + dRACKSPACING
        Next
        dStartX += dRACKSIZE + dRACKSPACING
    Next

    dStartX -= dRACKSPACING

End Sub

Private Function GetNewButton() As Button

    Dim btn As New Button
    btn.Width = dRACKSIZE
    btn.Height = dRACKSIZE
    btn.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red
    btn.BorderThickness = New Thickness(1)
    btn.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf Button_Click))

    Return btn

End Function

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim buttonClicked As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim text As String = DirectCast(buttonClicked.Content, TextBlock).Text
    MessageBox.Show("Button " & text & " Clicked")

End Sub
```

Comment: Kelly... You are awesome man... This actually works and is what I am looking exactly for. Thanks again

Comment: Can we add zoom in and out for this canvas? I tried with a slider and it didn't work

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I got the Mousewheel working now

Comment: I am trying to add button click event handler for some of the boxes created. `If (Not iRow = 0) AndAlso (iRow Mod 2 = 0) AndAlso (iRow Mod 4 = 0) Then
                    bdr.Background = Brushes.Orange

                    Dim btn As New Button
                    btn.Name = ("test").ToString()
                    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click

                End If `  Could you help me with this please?

Comment: I added code to my original post that replaces borders with buttons and hooks up the click event.

Comment: I am trying to make it more like dynamic. Meaning each of our locations have different warehouse layout so I am trying to pass the parameters but canvas children are hiding towards right. I am thinking of if there is something would actually make canvas adjust based on the child items.

Comment: BTW, I would appreciate if you can send me any of your tutorials or blogs on WPF.

Comment: I tried to create a Print preview for this but it seems that WPF has no print preview like Windows forms.  all the hardwork I did from last two weeks are now popped up like a water bubble. If anyone had Print preview of this canvas with zoom in and out options like in Windows forms . Please share your ideas/tutorials/code

Comment: Look at this solution for wpf window printing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175530/printing-of-wpf-window-on-one-page

Comment: I have been there. didn't help any

Comment: Why is this Window not showing horizontal scrollbar. Even after enabling it.

Comment: I am trying similar thing in a webform with table rows and cells and it looks like this logic doesn't work with that. Please see the below thread and help me out on that. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341975/create-a-dynamic-table-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

To the questions below in answer 1, Here is what I did. Most of the code is from SO but it is not actually doing the styles like width and height. Print Preview is done in the following way. I had a Print preview button in tool bar of XAML mainwindow and in code behind I had below code        `

```
Friend Sub DoPreview(title As String)
    Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()
    ' Dim visual As FlowDocumentScrollViewer = DirectCast(Me.FindName("cvsWarehouse"), FlowDocumentScrollViewer)
    Dim visual As Canvas = DirectCast(cvsWarehouse, Canvas)
    visual.Width = 1500
    visual.Height = 900
    Try
        ' write the XPS document
        Using doc As New XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Dim writer As XpsDocumentWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc)
            writer.Write(visual)
        End Using

        ' Read the XPS document into a dynamically generated
        ' preview Window 
        Using doc As New XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.Read)

            Dim fds As FixedDocumentSequence = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence()
            Dim s As String = _previewWindowXaml
            s = s.Replace("@@TITLE", title.Replace("'", "&apos;"))
            Using reader = New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(New StringReader(s))
                Dim preview As New Window
                preview.Width = 1500
                preview.Height = 900

                preview.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                preview.VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch
                preview = TryCast(System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(reader), Window)
                Dim dv1 As DocumentViewer = TryCast(LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(preview, "dv1"), DocumentViewer)
                dv1.Width = 1500
                dv1.Height = 900

                dv1.IsHitTestVisible = True
                dv1.VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch
                dv1.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                dv1.ApplyTemplate()
                dv1.Document = TryCast(fds, IDocumentPaginatorSource)
                preview.ShowDialog()
            End Using
        End Using
    Finally
        If File.Exists(fileName) Then
            Try
                File.Delete(fileName)
            Catch
            End Try
        End If
    End Try
End Sub`
```

And the my preview is like below 
[Print Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5WP5.png)

Neither I can do scroll bar nor the entire canvas which is wider is fit to the preview window. 
My actual Window with canvas is way wider like below 
[Actual canvas window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76pXb.png)
Could someone please correct the bug here?