# Create a dynamic table in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create a dynamic Table to display in web form content place holder.
I have a simple test with the below

```
Private Function createmyTab() As Table
    Dim tbl As New Table
    For i As Integer = 10 To 0 Step -1
        Dim tr As TableRow = New TableRow()
        For j As Integer = 5 To 0 Step -1
            'i = i + 1
            Dim tc As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim txtBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
            txtBox.Text = "RowNo:" & i & " " & "ColumnNo:" & " " & j
            ' Add the control to the TableCell
            tc.Controls.Add(txtBox)
            ' Add the TableCell to the TableRow
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            Exit For
        Next j
        ' Add the TableRow to the Table
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
    Next i
    Return tbl
End Function
```

The results are like below

```
Row 10 Col 5  Row 10 Col 4 Row 10 Col 3 Row 10 Col 2 Row 10 Col 1
Row 9  col 5  Row 9  col 4 Row 9 Col 3 Row 9 Col 2 Row 9 Col 1
Row 8  col 5  Row 8  col 4 Row 8 Col 3 Row 8 Col 2 Row 8 Col 1
Row 7  col 5  Row 7  col 4 Row 7 Col 3 Row 7 Col 2 Row 7 Col 1
Row 6  col 5  Row 6  col 4 Row 6 Col 3 Row 6 Col 2 Row 6 Col 1
```

And I want something like below

```
Row 10 col 5  Row 9 col 5  Row 8 col 5  Row 7 Row 6
Row 10 col 4  Row 9 col 4  Row 8 col 4  .     .
Row 10 col 3  Row 9 col 3  Row 8 col 3  .     ..
Row 10 col 2  Row 9 col 2  Row 8 col 2  .     ...
Row 10 col 1  Row 9 col 1  Row 8 col 1  .     ....
```

Actual purpose of doing this to achieve like below  [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQN3i.png)
(not buttons, but a text box)

I get the Numbers in correct format but AA018 AA016 AA014 ....should be like

```
AA018    AA017 AB018    AB017 AC018
AA016    AA015 AB016    AB015 AC016
AA014    AA013 AB014    AB013 AC014
```

Could someone please help me with this?
Please see the below image to get clear idea [Invalid Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwRjc.png)

Comment: placing \t in the string before placing it into the textbox is a tab space.

Comment: Its not about space. if you notice the image its horizontal. It should be displayed vertically as shown in the Image 1

Comment: sorry but i can't see your images... they all show up to me as a 1x1 white pixel... sorry if my comment doesn't help.

Comment: oh i see... what you have to do is basically add the row with a bunch of empty cells, then as you loop through the rows, add the cell/textbox text to the proper cell (Row[X]Cell[Y]) instead.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get what you mean

Comment: reading it again. I understood it. But that is not quite good. Bcoz I have to create something like this with hundreds of rows and columns. Not just 10.

Comment: I understand, but that is the only way to properly display the data like you want it as far as i know... the only other way would be to loop UP instead of down, and use the Table's InsertAt(0) to place the next row... but you would still have to create empty cells for the other rows (9, 8, 7)... OR, reverse your loops and use the "Col" counter instead for the actual physical row...

Comment: Could you give an example with "reverse your loops and use the "Col" counter instead for the actual physical row"

Comment: done. Try the second sample below and let me know of the result. Sorry if the code isn't perfect/doesn't compile properly but I am a C# person.

Comment: Well, this I tried already before posting the question. Didn't help though. Please see the last Image of what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your cells ahead of time, then fill them in to get the vertical aspect that you want.

```
Private Function createmyTab() As Table
    Dim tbl As New Table
    For i As Integer = 10 To 0 Step -1
         Dim tr as TableRow = New TableRow()
         For j as Integer =5 to 0 Step -1
              Dim tc as TableCell = New TableCell()
              tr.Cells.Add(tc);
         Next j
    tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
    Next i

    For i as Integer = 10 to 0 Step -1
        For j As Integer = 5 To 0 Step -1
            Dim txtBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
            txtBox.Text = "RowNo:" & i & " " & "ColumnNo:" & " " & j
            ' Add the control to the TableCell
            TableCell tc = tbl.Rows(i).Cells(i)
            tc.Controls.Add(txtBox)
            Exit For
        Next j
    Next i
    Return tbl
End Function
```

Another way as well would be to Loop UP instead of DOWN, reverse your current loop counters, and reverse the information being displayed in the code... like this:

```
Private Function createmyTab() As Table
    Dim tbl As New Table
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5 Step 1
        Dim tr As TableRow = New TableRow()
        For j As Integer = 0 To 10 Step 1
            'i = i + 1
            Dim tc As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim txtBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
            txtBox.Text = "RowNo:" & j & " " & "ColumnNo:" & " " & i
            ' Add the control to the TableCell
            tc.Controls.Add(txtBox)
            ' Add the TableCell to the TableRow
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            Exit For
        Next j
        ' Add the TableRow to the Table
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
    Next i
    Return tbl
End Function
```

Sorry if this code sample is slighty off or doesn't compile. I am more of a C# person.

Comment: This Didn't help... Please look at the Images of what I am expecting my program to do.